# Docker: SSH freezes on login

Tags: ssh, docker, docker-machine

I can succefully login to server using `ssh 111.111.111.111` without password. But after multiple ssh login, I can't access server for some while(it freezes when I try to login).

---

To tell the whole story I'm trying to create generic docker machine using following lines.

```
docker-machine create\
    --driver generic\
    --generic-ip-address=111.111.111.111\
    srv
```

All of the errors are ssh related, and they are quite randomly at different stages:

```
    Error getting SSH command: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
    command : cat /etc/os-release
    err     : exit status 255
    output  :
```

or:

```
    if ! type docker; then curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh -; fi
    SSH cmd err, output: exit status 255: 
    error installing docker:
```

After any of these error I can't login for somewhile. Please let me know if any log or confs is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since docker executes procedures via separate ssh command, somehow my provider detected me as an intruder for brute force attacks, changing the ssh port on remote server solved the problem.

Please view another question that I asked at
**[SSH parallel command execution freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563261/ssh-parallel-command-execution-freeze)** for this matter.