# SSH parallel command execution freeze

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to execute following code multiple times from one machine/ip

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 10`;
    do
        ssh 11.156.112.111 pwd
    done    

# I know that the script is useless, it's just for demonstration.
```

I can't execute the script in more than two terminal at the same time, when I try to run the script in the third terminal, it freezes and I can't login but I can login from another machine/ip.

my configs

```
# .ssh/config
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 10
    ServerAliveCountMax 10

# sshd_config
    UsePAM no
    MaxSessions 100
    MaxStartups 100
```

Here is the output of verbose mode, it freezes on the last line:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/neelix/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/neelix/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/neelix/.ssh/config line 11: Applying options for 11.156.112.111 
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "11.156.112.111" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 11.156.112.111 [11.156.112.111] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/neelix/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/neelix/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
```

Comment: Try to run `ssh -v 11.156.112.111 pwd` to catch the point where ssh stuck

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Is the script you mentioned in your question is the exact scrip that stuck?

Comment: Can you run it again, and [edit] again, running with `-vvv` to increase verbosity of the logging?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same, it doesn't matter if I use `pwd` or `ls` or something else, it stucks after first 3 or 4 iterations then `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer` after some while some more iterations... the loop takes 20 mins to complete.

Comment: This behavior is on the first terminal, but on the second or third, it freezes at the beginning.

Comment: @MattClark I've updated the log.

Comment: hmmm, interesting. When I run this agains my server, the very next line in the output is `debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1`, which is the SSH server identifying itself, meaning that your ssh server is not actually responding to you... Do you have access to the server? Can you try restarting the service?

Comment: this `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer` thing could point to server issues. Do you have access to the server? If you do, please run `dmesg -T` or `less /var/log/messages` and search for ssh related messages

Comment: When I restart the server, everything works fine again, unless I run the scripts again. I've turned off the `PasswordAuthentication`, is it related to server not identifiying itself?

Comment: Try advises from here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151860/ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer . Some of them could work for you :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out.

Comment: It seems to me like a firewall problem. Probably somewhere `connlimit` or `recent` module is being used which limits number of connections over predefined time. What your `iptables -L -n` states? Can you disable firewall for a while to test it?

Comment: No rule is set for iptables. Further more I've checked with another system the same thing happens. But from another user on the server everything works fine. I don't have access to check from another server on the same subnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many support tickets with my hosting provider, I found out that they had IDS(Intrusion Detection System) and it detected me as someone who is doing a brute force attack on port 22 and changing my port fixed the problem.

For future readers the comments above are quite helpful to narrow down the problem, specially answers to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151860/ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer). I hope it saves someone else a couple of days!